# Can't connect two remote hosts in Java RMI

Tags: java, rmi

My server's code looks like:

```
Registry r = java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1399);
r.rebind("Chat", new IRC());
```

and my client's code is

```
IRCInterface remoteObject = (IRCInterface) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:1399/Chat");
String history = remoteObject.read();
```

on the localhost it works correctly, but I can't connect two remote computers (hosts).
I've turned off all firewalls.

What's wrong?

The console outputs:

```
Error: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 150.254.79.20; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Comment: I'd think I'd read a basic networking book first...

Comment: It's a very general recommendation ;)

Comment: "Can't" is not an adequate problem description. Please provide error messages, stack dumps, etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:1399/Chat");
```

`localhost` in above lookup should be replaced with remotehost IP (or) machine name. Otherwise lookup happens on only local machine.

Comment: :) Yes I know about it, but it doesn't matter. I put the hosts` IPs there.

Comment: @daroPL: If put IP, what is happening? Are you getting any exception? If so, please update question with stack trace.